# How to parse current offers with the Java SDK

Tags: java-sdk

Sorry for another illiterate question, but how the heck do you parse the https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_ID/offers page? There is almost no documentation on this.

I have successfully submitted an offer to the Stellar distributed exchange, but now I need to edit it and view other offers I may have created.

It looks like these are the class the SDK uses, but I'm at a loss for correct implementation: https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/responses/OfferResponse.html and https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/requests/OffersRequestBuilder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package org.stellar.sdk;

import org.stellar.sdk.responses.OfferResponse;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.Page;

public class GetOffersForAccount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server("https://horizon.stellar.org");
        try {
            KeyPair account = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GB5XET2RN2AM2U7Y6UTAJGEMNGFGYUKU3CLGMBVYKZSGAK37XMZQLM2C");
            Page<OfferResponse> offers = server.offers().forAccount(account).execute();
            System.out.println(offers.getRecords().get(0).getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```